# Connect to bluetooth device on startup

Tags: boot, raspbian-wheezy, bluetooth

I want my Raspberry Pi to be a Music Server. So I connected some speakers and everything works fine now. Tho only problem is that i have to connect the speakers manually after each startup.

Is there a way to automatically connect my speakers when the Raspberry boots up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may put whatever you need in `/etc/rc.local` and don't forget to make it an executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`